# Magento - American Express credit cart option not appearing on checkout payment method for UK country

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am using paypal to accept pcredit card payment for UK country.

I have configured from magento backend.

I multi store in website.

One for UK and another for US.

it's working for US but same configuration not working for UK store.

Here is screenshot:

[image]

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Now i got solutions

as paypal direct not providing Amex(American Express) for UK

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/

[image]